# How to switch between two azure SQL databases dynamically from web app in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I have deployed web app and SQL Database in Region A and SQL database in Region B.

When SQL Database from Region A is down i want my web app to connect SQL database from Region B dynamically.

Comment: are these db's replicated, is this a .net app

Comment: yes, this is .net app. Both the db's are sync together using Azure SQL sync.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Azure SQL Database Active Geo-Replication...

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-geo-replication-overview/

...combined with a Powershell script (or manual Azure portal config, as you prefer) that:

1) initiates the failover to a secondary SQL replica (which becomes the primary)

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-disaster-recovery/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt619393.aspx

2) updates the web app config to use the new primary replica's connection string

[Adding an App Settings to existing Azure Web Application using Azure Power Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543778/adding-an-app-settings-to-existing-azure-web-application-using-azure-power-shell)

I'm assuming you're using Azure App Service Web Apps... if not then you'd need some other programmatic means to (for instance) update the web.config of a site deployed in a VM, etc.

Comment: You can use the built-in monitoring https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-pool-manage-portal/ or if that's not sufficient there are several third parties who provide fine-grained alerts, etc.  http://cloudmonix.com/  https://www.cotega.com/