# Azure powershell slot specific appsetting

Tags: powershell, azure, appsettings, slot

I'm trying to create a script to set / update appsettings in an Azure web app slot using powershell. Using the examples in [Adding an App Settings to existing Azure Web Application using Azure Power Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543778/adding-an-app-settings-to-existing-azure-web-application-using-azure-power-shell) it works.

My problem is that I want "Slot setting" to be true. In all the examples I've found and in resources.azure.com, the settings are always name/value pairs, with no property to specify the value as "Slot setting".

Is this even possible to script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes when using the `Set-AzureWebsite` command you can do 
`Set-AzureWebsite -SlotStickyAppSettingNames @("setting name")`

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with Azure RM (Resource Manager) commands? E.g. Set-AzureRMWebAppSlot or New-AzureRMWebAppSlot?