# Deploy app settings to azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, appveyor

Need help in finding a way to deploy my application's custom app setting via either -
1. Using appsettings.json created by my .funproj (vs tools for 2015)
2. appveyor's environment variables
3. Any other trick

All I want is to avoid having to set these things manually in the portal and have them source controlled (better - using deployment, ex. - appveyor's secure environment variables)

Thanks in advance!
below are an example of portal settings I am targetting -

[image]

example of appveyor's environment variable setting -

```
environment:
    SolutionDir: $(APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER)\
    my_var1: value1
    my_var2: value2
```

sample usage in function app (run.csx) -

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;

public static void Run(string input, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# manually triggered function called with input: {input}");
    log.Info($"This is a custom setting: {GetEnvironmentVariable("my_var1")}");
}

public static string GetEnvironmentVariable(string name)
{
    return name + ": " +
        System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
}
```

Comment: how does appveyor deploy this? ARM Template?

Comment: using web deploy

Comment: Maybe you can use Azure PowerShell (already installed on build workers) as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543778/adding-an-app-settings-to-existing-azure-web-application-using-azure-power-shell) as `after_deploy` script?

Comment: [Here](http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/6107-azure-powershell-service-principal-login-not-working) are some samples on how to use Azure PowerShell on AppVeyor securely.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by arm templates. A sample arm template to do this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "functionappname": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "serviceplanname": "[concat('functionserviceplan-',parameters('functionappname'),'-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
    "functionstoragename": "[substring(toLower(concat('st',parameters('functionappname'), uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))),0,24)]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
        "name": "[variables('serviceplanname')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
        "kind": "functionapp",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Y1",
            "tier": "Dynamic",
            "size": "Y1",
            "family": "Y",
            "capacity": 0
        },
        "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "properties": { "name": "[variables('serviceplanname')]" }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "[variables('functionstoragename')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
      "sku": { "name": "Standard_LRS" },
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "kind": "Storage"
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "kind": "functionapp",
        "name": "[parameters('functionappname')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('functionappname')]",
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('serviceplanname'))]",
            "hostNames": [ "[concat(parameters('functionappname'),'.azurewebsites.net')]" ],
            "enabledHostNames": [
                "[concat(parameters('functionappname'),'.azurewebsites.net')]",
                "[concat(parameters('functionappname'),'.scm.azurewebsites.net')]"
            ],
            "siteConfig": {
                "appSettings": [
                    { "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION", "value": "~1" },
                    { "name": "AzureWebJobsDashboard", "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('functionstoragename'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('functionstoragename')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value)]" },
                    { "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage", "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('functionstoragename'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('functionstoragename')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value)]" },
                    { "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION", "value": "6.5.0" }
                ]
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('serviceplanname'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('functionstoragename'))]"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can read how to automate deployments from VSTS: [use-vsts-to-deploy-functions-as-infrastructure-as-code](https://pgroene.wordpress.com/2017/01/27/use-vsts-to-deploy-functions-as-infrastructure-as-code/)

Comment: @lindydonna-msft do you have an example powershell script?