# Change WebApp AppSetting values when creating a new Slot

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-deployment-slots

When creating a new Slot for an Azure WebApp, how can I successfully change one or more of the AppSettings?

The [docs for `New-AzureRmWebAppSlot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/new-azurermwebappslot?view=azurermps-4.4.0) suggest that there is a parameter called `-AppSettingsOverrides`, but that does not work.

It should be noted however that the linked docs seem to incorrectly reference the `New-AzureRmWebApp` Cmdlet, so I can't be sure if the parameter is actually valid (although it seems to be accepted without error).

Here is the code that I am running.

```
New-AzureRmWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $webAppName -Slot $slotName -AppSettingsOverrides @{"FUNCTION_APP_EDIT_MODE" = "readwrite"} -ErrorAction Stop
```

Has anyone else experienced this seemlying incorrect behaviour, and if so, how did you fix it?

**My Azure version is 3.5.0.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create Slot firstly, then use [`Set-AzureRmWebAppSlot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/set-azurermwebappslot?view=azurermps-4.4.0) to change AppSetting. Following script works for me.

```
$myResourceGroup = "shuiapp"
$mySite = "shuicli"
$slotName = "Test1"
$webApp = Get-AzureRMWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup -Name $mySite -Slot $slotName
$appSettingList = $webApp.SiteConfig.AppSettings

$hash = @{}
ForEach ($kvp in $appSettingList) {
    $hash[$kvp.Name] = $kvp.Value
}


$hash['ExistingKey2'] = "NewValue12"

Set-AzureRMWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup -Name $mySite -AppSettings $hash -Slot $slotName
```

[image]

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543778/adding-an-app-settings-to-existing-azure-web-application-using-azure-power-shell) will be helpful.

Comment: That should work.  We use Octopus to deploy a Function App and step 2 is basically what you have proposed alreay, taking Octopus variables and adding/updating them.  Obviously I'd prefer if things worked as described, but at least this is a fairly painless workaround.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to this [dingmeng-xue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/12181#issuecomment-645213032) on Github for pointing this out but for the benefit of everyone reading Stackoverflow, it appears that the cmdlet doesn't a) check that `-SourceWebApp` and `-AppSettingsOverrides` are set together and b) only does a null check if `$SourceWebApp` is defined and silently does nothing even if `$AppSettingsOverrides` was defined. So you might set them both and test if that solves the issue.